# Mysqli não retorna resultados

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou querendo trazer resultados de uma tabela mysql, porém não está funcionando. O que está me causando estranheza é que quando a informação tem acentos, não funciona, sendo que no banco de dados os acentos estão corretos. Vejam:

```
include("includes/conexao.php"); // Faço a conexão

$escola = htmlentities(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"BuscarEscola"));
$escolaSeguro = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$escola);

$sqlEscolas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM escolas WHERE nome = 'Colégio Inclusão';");
$jmEscolas = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlEscolas);
echo "Nome " .$jmEscolas->nome;
```

Comment: Qual a `engine` do seu banco de dados ?

Comment: Em resumo, você tem que se certificar que todos os encodings das suas coisas estão no mesmo padrão **a começar pelo editor de código**. Mais detalhes nas respostas da pergunta linkada acima.

Comment: No caso do acento o charset do bd tem que estar unicode tb. Mas porque você está usando o operador = em uma pesquisa por nome? Não seria mais lógico utilizar like '%Colégio Inclusão%'?

Comment: @NorivanOliveira se ele quer uma busca exata, o `LIKE` não faz sentido. Aliás, o que eu vejo de gente usando `LIKE`onde não precisa aqui no site é absurdo. Além de ser péssimo, pois `LIKE` com coringa no começo não aproveita índice.

Answer (score -1):

Defina UTF8 no seu projeto.

No próprio cabeçalho HTML de seus documentos você pode fazer isso. Veja:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Porém não é 100% das vezes que o servidor aceita essa instrução HTML e continua “desconfigurando” caracteres especiais.

Em casos assim, ao invés de definir a codificação pelo cabeçalho HTML, defina através da função ini_set do próprio php.

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
?>
```

Comment: Colegas, resolvi da seguinte forma: mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); Espero que ajude os outros colegas que passarem pelo mesmo problema.